# VScode didn't recognize python3

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just installed my ubuntu on my PC then i installed python 3 & Vscode on my PC. but my VS Code didn't recognize the python3. maybe my vs code looking for my python. how to solve this?

In my VS Code when I compiled the class then the output:

```
python -u "/home/kisiniki/Documents/python/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
```

In my terminal already installed python 3.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to see if you are able to run the same command in terminal.

```
python -u "/home/kisiniki/Documents/python/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
```

If you are getting the same error, "python: not found", then likely python installation was not completely successful, you can either uninstall and reinstall or you can try to update PATH to contain the folder containing the python executable. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/637848/how-to-reset-python-path-to-usr-bin-python for more detail.

If you can run the command in terminal, then that means VS Code cannot find your installed python.  See if you need to edit some settings in VS Code for it to know what python executable to run. See 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you used the command `python` without having an activated virtual environment or not using `python3` or `python3.6`. Try it with `python3.6` and see if that fixes it. If it doesn't then Python isn't on your `PATH`.